# I could use some help stylising a glossary in an article footnote (such as "acr - acronym, USA - united states of america") - how to achieve that?

Tags: acronyms, article, glossary

I would like to add my glossary as a string in a footnote. Therefore, I have cobbled together the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[nopostdot,acronym,nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries} 

\newcommand{\chapternote}[1]{{%
  \let\thempfn\relax% Remove footnote number printing mechanism
  \footnotetext[0]{#1}% Print footnote text
}}

\newacronym{dag}{DAG}{directed acyclic graphic}
\newacronym{usa}{USA}{United States of America}
\makeglossaries

\title{Title}
\author{Me \and I}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
    This is my banger of a first sentence, it's absolutely glorious.\chapternote{\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long,title={}]} 
    The \gls{usa} can be visualised in a \gls{dag}.
\end{document}
```

There are a few issues with this, as the absence of the glossary title leaves quite a bit of white space, which I'd rather not have. Further, this code does not really generate an in-line glossary, just the traditional two-column list - how do I change the output to something like "DAG - directed acyclic graphic, USA - United States of America".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not completely automated, but it does work. Sort of.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[nopostdot,acronym,nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\chapternote}[1]{{%
  \let\thempfn\relax% Remove footnote number printing mechanism
  \footnotetext[0]{#1}% Print footnote text
}}

\newacronym{dag}{DAG}{directed acyclic graph}
\newacronym{usa}{USA}{United States of America}
\makeglossaries

% Define a command to format glossary entries
\newcommand{\formatglossaryentries}[1]{%
  \textbf{Acronyms:}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \@ \acrshort{##1} -- \glsdesc{##1},%
  }%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}

\title{Title}
\author{Me \and I}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
    This is my banger of a first sentence, it's absolutely glorious.
    
    \chapternote{\formatglossaryentries{dag,usa}}
    
    The \gls{usa} can be visualized in a \gls{dag}.
\end{document}
```